# mac terminal running a script on startup, how to stop?

Tags: macos, terminal, osx-yosemite, bash

I created a bash_aliases file and put it in bash_profile, but the problem is every time I start the terminal, it is running that script. 
Any ideas how to stop it?

Comment: That is what bash_profile is supposed to do, run when terminal is started. If you don't want a script to run, remove its entry from bash_profile.

Comment: @Ali please put it as answer and I will tag it as one. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what bash_profile is supposed to do, run when terminal is started. If you don't want a script to run, remove its entry from bash_profile.